# how to round off a float

Tags: python

i want to round off a float to 3 dp in python with 00 in the end if the float don't have 3 dp
like 15.4 into 15.400
thank you.

programme:

```
x=round(15.4)
```

result:
15.400

Comment: That is not rounding...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello its pretty simple you can do something like this

```
a=15.4
b=("%.3f" % a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

The "rounding" you are talking about can only be done if you convert the float to a string. This is usually only done for display purposes. In this case you can use a so-called f-string to do this formatting:

```
x = 15.4
print(f"{x:.3f}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`15.4` and `15.400` are the same **number**. `round()` returns a number. What you want is to have a different **representation** when you convert it to a string.

You need to do string formatting. Just copying the other answers here, there are two ways.

- f-strings:

```
n = 15.4
n_str = f"{n:.3f}"
```

- %-formatting:

```
n_str = "%.3f" % n
```